# Why is the binding element not getting bound to my service?

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf

I'm getting the same error over and over again.

This is my code for web.config :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true"/>
  <add key="api_url" value="http://182.73.171.198/"/>
  </appSettings>
  <!--For a description of web.config changes for .NET 4.5 see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=235367. The following attributes be can set on the <httpRuntime> tag.
      <system.Web>
        <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
      </system.Web>
  -->
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5">
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="System.Data.OracleClient, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
      </assemblies>
    </compilation>
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.1"/>
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the values below to false before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <protocolMapping>
      <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https" />
    </protocolMapping>

    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="basicHttp" allowCookies="true"
                 maxReceivedMessageSize="20000000"
                 maxBufferSize="20000000"
                 maxBufferPoolSize="20000000">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="32"
               maxArrayLength="200000000"
               maxStringContentLength="200000000"/>
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>

    <services>
      <service name="Netlockapi.INetlockapi">
        <endpoint binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="" bindingName="basicHttp" contract="Netlockapi.INetlockapi" />
      </service>
    </services>

    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true"/>
  </system.serviceModel>

  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
    <!--
        To browse web app root directory during debugging, set the value below to true.
        Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing web app folder information.
      -->
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true"/>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

I'm tired of trying to get the NetlockApi bound to the binding element. I'm always getting the same error as maxReceivedMessageSize exceeded. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

```
<bindings>
     <basicHttpBinding>
         <binding name="basicHttp" closeTimeout="00:01:00" openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00" allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" maxBufferSize="2097152" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="2097152" messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered" useDefaultWebProxy="true">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="2097152" maxArrayLength="2097152" maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384"/>
              <security mode="None">
                  <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None" realm=""/>
                  <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default"/>
               </security>
         </binding>
    </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
```

Comment: Still getting the same error. Could you kindly suggest as to what might have gone wrong?